# "Not unique table/alias" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, unique, alias

The code below gives me **Not unique table/alias: 'presentations'**

I've read several articles about this and I'm pretty sure the solution is to use aliases for my tables. I just can't understand how I create aliases or where I should add them.

Could someone please try to explain it for me?

Thanks!

```
SELECT categories.name, categories.sub_name, parts.name
FROM categories
INNER JOIN presentations
ON categories.id=presentations.category
INNER JOIN presentations
ON parts.id=presentations.parts
WHERE presentations.id=5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining the same table 2 times and hence you need to provide the unique alias name. However looks like you are looking for `parts` table and hence need to join that table

```
SELECT 
categories.name, 
categories.sub_name, 
parts.name
FROM categories
INNER JOIN presentations ON categories.id=presentations.category
INNER JOIN parts ON parts.id=presentations.parts
WHERE presentations.id=5;
```

For better readability you can always give some short alias name something as

```
select
c.name,
c.sub_name,
p.name as parts_name
from categories c
join presentations pr on pr.category = c.id
join parts p on p.id = pr.parts
where pr.id = 5
```

Comment: Thanks! So the problem had nothing to with aliases, but rather that I joined two tables wrong? I thought i joined the "parts"-table with this: `INNER JOIN presentations
ON parts.id=presentations.parts`I'm also wondering why `as parts_name` was added for just one(1) of the three columns that are selected?

Comment: Yes thats the issue, however when you join the same table multiple time, it may be needed in future make sure you give unique alias names for the joins else you will get the same above error ! Now `parts_name` I have added so that the application script while getting the data knows which item its getting, if you leave it as `name` then you have 2 names from 2 tables and it could be a conflict while you display the data.

Comment: But if you remove `as parts_name` it still says `p.name` which should be enough, if `c.name` is enough? Your script still work even when I remove `as parts_name`.

Comment: that will be in your mysql terminal or phpmyadmin, but in the app level say in PHP it will refer `name` as the index.

Comment: Oh, now I get it! I forgot about that. Thank you very much for explaining this.

Comment: yes its always better when you are fetching data from multiple tables having same column names to give some alias for the column names so to uniquely identify them in the application level.

Answer (score 2):

After table name or field name you can give alias name and you can use it.

```
SELECT C.name, C.sub_name, PT.name
FROM categories C
INNER JOIN presentations P
ON C.id=P.category
INNER JOIN parts PT
ON PT.id=P.parts
WHERE P.id=5;
```

In above example `C`,`PT`,`P` is alias name of `categories`,`presentation`,`parts` table respectively.

Comment: Thanks alot! I thought there were standard aliases but now I understand that I can name them myself.